# Writing an unsigned long datatype to a binary file

Tags: c

I am having trouble figuring out how to write an unsigned long variable (phone number in this case) to a binary file.

I have this

```
int main()
{
   char useInput[100];
   unsigned long *phoneNum;
   FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "wb");


   while (strncmp(useInput,"exit",4)){

   printf("Phone #: ");
   scanf("%lu",phoneNum);
   fwrite(&phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum), 1, fp);

   printf("Fname: ");
   fgets(useInput,100,stdin);
   useInput[strlen(useInput)-1]='\0';
   fwrite(&useInput, strlen(useInput), 1,fp);

   }

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;

}
```

Everything compiles fine with -ansi and -Wall flags. When I run it, it allows me to enter the phone number, but when I hit enter after I'm done typing the phone number, it says Segmentation fault.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What does `phoneNum` point to when you start using it?

Comment: How are you going to *read* the `useInput` back again, since you're not even writing the null terminator!

Comment: also, I don't believe that everything compiles fine with `-Wall`, you should get loads of errors. Please try `-Wall -Werror` if you don't believe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You code has multiple issues. I commented these issues.

```
int main()
{
   char useInput[100];
   unsigned long *phoneNum;
   FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "wb");


   while (strncmp(useInput,"exit",4)){ // useInput is not initialized for the first iteration 

   printf("Phone #: ");
   scanf("%lu",phoneNum); // phoneNum is not initialized
   fwrite(&phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum), 1, fp);

   printf("Fname: ");
   fgets(useInput,100,stdin);
   useInput[strlen(useInput)-1]='\0';
   fwrite(&useInput, strlen(useInput), 1,fp);

   } // this closing curly bracket is missing

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;

}
```

[A live test of your code](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/Zb7aH4txt4Q2E2ym), you can fixes these issues and test it again.